# why pageInit callback not called when cached page load from url

Tags: html-framework-7

I have domCache enabled

```
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    domCache: true //enable inline pages
});
```

and dom is something like

```
 <div class="pages">
          <!-- Home page -->
          <div class="page" data-page="index">
            <div class="page-content">
              <p>Home page</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- About page -->
          <div class="page cached" data-page="about">
            <div class="page-content">
              <p>About page</p>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

then in url i type

http://localhost/myapp/#!/#about
so that i can get to about page directly, as expected, about page shows up.

Expected Behavior

```
myApp.onPageInit("about",function(page){
   // code here should be executed
})
```

Actual Behavior

Code not executed.
I also enable a plugin which has a hook to pageInit event, it shows the pageInit has been called for page "about". However the onPageInit callback is not called.